# com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: Caller not whitelisted to call this API

Tags: android, google-authentication

I flow the document like this https://developers.google.cn/identity/one-tap/android/get-saved-credentials now it cause the problem  Caller not whitelisted to call this API.

What should I do? Can it be whitelisted?

Answer (score 3):

This appears to happen if you use the API too many times over a short period of time. If you wait about 15 minutes, this error will go away. Clearing the Google Play services storage app will not fix this.

Answer (score 1):

It might be worthwhile to dial `*#*#66382723#*#*`, as described in the document.
https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/get-saved-credentials#disable-one-tap

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes u just might forget to specify scope for your project in the https://console.cloud.google.com/.

[image]